# How to get the total of sales for each product, aggregation of foreignkey

Tags: sql, django, database, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a small django project. In my models.py I have a Product class like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
     ...
```

And I have a `Sales` class like:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
     item = models.ForeignKey(Product)
     quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to display a list of all my products with the **total** of sales for each product...

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the product using **[`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values)** then aggregate to get the total price.

```
#assumption
class Product(models.Model):
     price = models.DecimalField(...)
     ...

Sales.objects.values('item').annotate(total=Sum(F('quantity') * F('item__price')))

# provide more infomation if you want to loop in template
Sales.objects.values('item').annotate(
   price_sum = Sum(F('quantity') *  F('item__price')), 
   quantity_sum = Sum('quantity'),
   product_name = F('item__name')
)
```

**template**

```
{% for sale in sales %}
    {{ sale.product_name }}
    {{ sale.quantity_sum }}
    {{ sale.price_sum }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I did what you suggested like :
sales = Sales.objects....
And I passed the sales in a context variable to my template.
And then in my template, I did something like
{% for sale in sales %}
{{ sale.item}} : {{ sale.quantity }}
{% endfor %}

But I think I'm going wrong about this as I got a strange output that I didn't really understand...

Comment: @MounirBenhalima After `group by` operation, the queryset is squeezed and only contains the aggregated result for each item. it looks like a list of dict `[{"id":1, "total": 256.6}, {"id":2, ...}]`, you have to loop like you loop on a normal `dict`